# Converting a history to a script?

Tags: bash, scripting, zsh, command-history

Often times I've typed in a bunch of commands when I realize that I am going to keep typing them in and that I would really like a script.

Now I understand that no matter how I save my history, I am going to have to edit it to clean things up, but would like to hear suggestions on how to save my history so that it is close to a usable script.

Answer (score 4):

The way i'd approach this is:

`history -a` - add new lines to history file

`ctrl-x, ctrl-e` - open an editor to make a quick script (in vi, for me)

`:r ~/.bash_history | tail -n 20` - read in the last 20 commands from history file.

Answer (score 3):

If you type `history` in the shell, you will see a list of recent commands. You can see this to a script by `history > my_script` or something (or just copy it from the ~/.bash_history file).

From the my_script file you can remove the unnecessary commands, add the shebang line, typically `#!/bin/bash`, and make it executable `chmod +x my_script` and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

A  bash one liner  approach:

```
history | tail -20 |cut -c 8- > newscript.txt;  chmod 777 newscript.txt
```

If you add shebang, you can make this a script.

Comment: Don't know why someone voted this down, it works quite well IF your bash_history is accurate... either way, very quick edit. Upvoted.

Comment: Make it a real oneliner - add shebang line: `; sed -i '1 i\#!/usr/bin/bash' newscript.txt`

Comment: BTW  - you could clear based on fields rather than chars: `tail -20|tr -s '[:blank:]' ' '|cut -d' ' -f 3-`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be to use an editor with a macro language.

- Import a bunch of lines with cut and paste
- Filter out output of the commands by grepping for your prompt
- Remove the prompt from the beginning of lines
- insert a shebang at the beginning of the file

A significant prompt will help to make this work in most cases. For session sizes of more than a few screen pages, it will not be very comfortable.